# iOS App: Enabling logging with minimal changes to the code

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, logging

I have an code for an iOS application. How would I enable logging in some of the UI methods like say `ViewDidLoad` `ViewWillAppear` etc with minimal changes to the code base?

I was asked this question in an iOS interview.

I told him that I would include the `Google Analytics` framework to capture the info. He did not the answer in terms of which framework we used.

But rather the approach that we would follow to enable/capture logging information with minimal code change.

Was wondering if there is any inbuilt mechanism to log required info (say capture NSLog into a log file) which could be turned-on by setting/enabling some flag in project settings?

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic example of [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). Logging is a so called **cross-cutting concern**, you can dig more into it by searching on the internet. In iOS this programming paradigm is usually implemented using [method swizzling](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/), again there are some great resources out there about it. A nice library that makes method swizzling easier is [aspects](https://github.com/steipete/Aspects). Basically if you use this you don't have to change anything (just add stuff) to add logging to an application.